# ExtJS 5: initConfig method & Observable mixin

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

Since I don't seem to be getting any answers on the [Sencha Forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?298613-ExtJS-5-initConfig-method-amp-Observable-mixin), I just repeat my question here:

I'm currently migrating from 4.2.1 to 5.1.0.107 and am having problems understanding some stuff:

Sencha dev [evant](http://www.sencha.com/forum/member.php?2950-evant) states [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?286810-Automatic-initConfig%28%29-call-in-ext-js-5-doesnt-seem-to-work&p=1048756&viewfull=1#post1048756) that `initConfig` only needs to be called manually from the constructor in classes which don't use the Observable mixin.

The first example of the Observable mixin in the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.mixin.Observable) says otherwise by manually calling it.

Running the code as is from the docs results in an exception (hasListeners is undefined) which can be resolved by placing `this.mixins.observable.constructor.call(this, config);` into the constructor.

Also it seems to me that `initConfig` can be removed from the example code from the docs without any drawbacks (at least none that I was able to reproduce)...

The only difference in the 2 codes below is in the Employee constructor...

[Erroneous fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/itl) (Code copied from docs)

```
Ext.define('Employee', {
    mixins: ['Ext.mixin.Observable'],

    config: {
        fullName: ''
    },

    constructor: function(config) {
        this.initConfig(config);  // We need to initialize the config options when the class is instantiated
    },

    quitJob: function() {
        this.fireEvent('quit');
    }
});

var newEmployee = Ext.create('Employee', {
    fullName: 'Ed Spencer',

    listeners: {
        quit: function() {
            alert(this.getFullName() + " has quit!");
        }
    }
});

try {
    newEmployee.quitJob(); // Throws exception since hasListener is undefined
} catch (exc) {
    alert('Error occurred: ' + exc.message);
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/itm) (removed initConfig & initialize mixin correctly)

```
Ext.define('Employee', {
    mixins: ['Ext.mixin.Observable'],

    config: {
        fullName: ''
    },

    constructor: function(config) {
        // Make code work by removing call to initConfig and initializing the observable mixin
        //this.initConfig(config);  // We need to initialize the config options when the class is instantiated
        this.mixins.observable.constructor.call(this, config);
    },

    quitJob: function() {
        this.fireEvent('quit');
    }
});

var newEmployee = Ext.create('Employee', {        
    fullName: 'Ed Spencer',

    listeners: {
        quit: function() {
            alert(this.getFullName() + " has quit!");
        }
    }
});

try {
    newEmployee.quitJob(); // Will log 'Ed Spencer has quit!'
} catch (exc) {
    alert('Error occurred: ' + exc.message);
}
```

I'd be really happy if anyone could answer the following questions:

- Do we need to call `initConfig` in the constructor manually when using the Observable mixin
- Do we need to call the mixin constructor manually?
- What is the difference in using `Ext.mixin.Observable` and `Ext.util.Observable`

Thanks & best regards

Comment: You're asking what is essentially a challenging technical support question. What makes you think that it has greater chance of being answered here rather than in Sencha forums? No, really. I always wondered why people do that.

Comment: As stated in the first line of my question, I've already asked it in the [Sencha forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?298613-ExtJS-5-initConfig-method-amp-Observable-mixin) before I did here but didn't get any answer there (as well as here). I usually do this to increase my chances of getting an answer and to be honest, in my experience it's more likely to get an answer here, than on the Sencha forum...

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was asking: why do you think that a question like this has a greater chance of being answered here? In Sencha forums we have support engineers reading every thread, creating tickets and escalating them to core devs when needed. There is no official support on SO; AFAIK only Evan and I are looking at it from time to time. So if either of us has time, and the moon is right, you might get an answer. Otherwise, tough luck.

Comment: To reiterate: there are questions, and questions. If you're asking something along the lines of "I need my panel X to do thing Y, how do I do that", chances are that somebody around here has already done that and they can share their experience. But your question calls for deep knowledge of how 5.x config system works, as well as intimate familiarity with Observable mixin; honestly if you find someone on SO who can answer that, please don't hesitate to point them out to me. We're short on good devs, and we're always hiring. :)

Comment: I always wonder why people don't just ignore questions that irritate them, rather than trying to make the OP feel stupid for asking. Someone needs an ego boost by berating others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an excerpt from [ExtJs 5.1 Upgrade Guide](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/guides/upgrades_migrations/extjs_upgrade_guide.html) -

> **"Unification of Ext.util.Observable and Ext.mixin.Observable APIs As mentioned in What’s New in Ext JS 5.1, Ext JS 5.1 still has two
>   Observable classes (Ext.mixin.Observable, and Ext.util.Observable),
>   but their API differences have been eliminated. There is only one
>   exception: Ext.mixin.Observable calls initConfig in its constructor
>   whereas Ext.util.Observable uses the legacy Ext.apply approach to copy
>   config object properties onto the instance. We recommend that
>   applications use Ext.mixin.Observable going forward, but we will
>   continue to support Ext.util.Observable for the foreseeable future
>   since many classes internal to the framework and in user code depend
>   upon its behavior."**